# Post to a Chatter feed as a different user than the logged un user from a Trigger

Tags: trigger, chatter, feeditem, connect-api

I have a trigger that posts to a Project Object's feed and @mentions someone. The only problem is that I need to be able to post the message as another user, not the user who is logged in. How can I do this? Here is my trigger.

```
trigger autoProjectChatter on Milestone1_Project__c ( after update) {
  for(Milestone1_Project__c project : Trigger.New) {
    if (project.Project_stage__c == 'Ready to Deliver') {

        string what = project.Id;
        string name = 'Album';

        String communityId = null;
        ConnectApi.FeedType feedType = ConnectApi.FeedType.Record;

        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment;
        ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegment = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();

        messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

        mentionSegment.id = '005j0000000Y3tO';
        messageInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegment);

        textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment.text = ' Brenda, I am pleased to announce that we have completed the project under budget, and well within our proposed timeline!';
        messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

        input.body = messageInput;
        //input.subjectId = t.whatID;


        ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItemRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(communityId, feedType, what, input, null);







       }  
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the ConnectApi classes currently don't support posting as another user. See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_differences.htm

The FeedItem SObject API supports impersonation, but it doesn't support posting @-mentions. So it's currently not possible to make an @-mention as another user.